# Where are windows 10 defender offline scan logs/results?

Tags: windows, log-files, anti-virus, eventviewer

I can't find any events or log files,
are there such records somewhere or WD reports only if it finds something?

Windows 10 pro,
drive is encrypted with bitlocker (might affects somehow?)

Comment: There's a History tab in the Windows Defender GUI. Look there.

Answer (score 13):

Windows Defender adds entries to the Event Viewer in the following location:

Event Viewer >> Applications and Services Logs >> Microsoft >> Windows >> Windows Defender >> Operational

Where you'll see:
Windows Defender scan has started. (Event ID 1000)
Windows Defender scan has finished. (Event ID 1001)
Windows Defender signature version has been updated. (2000)

Comment: Offline scan results are NOT logged at this location though.

Comment: For me the Defender Event Log is completely empty. Anything I need to enable ?

Answer (score 11):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17466/windows-defender-offline-help-protect-my-pc), any threats detected by the offline scanner will show up in the Threat History (where the online scanner also records any viruses found):

> Where can I find scan results?
>
> To see the Windows Defender Offline scan results:
>
> Select Start , and then select Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security  > Virus & threat protection .
>   On the Virus & threat protection screen, do one of the following:
>
> - In current version of Windows 10: Under Current threats, select Scan options, and then select Threat history.
> - In previous versions of Windows: Select Threat history.

The log showing the offline scan run seems to be stored in a file below `C:\Windows\Microsoft Antimalware\Support`, using the naming scheme `MPLog-<date>-<time>.log` (e.g. `MPLog-20181217-055720.log`).
You can tell that it is an offline scan log by the following line somewhere at the beginning:

`2018-12-17T04:57:20.837Z [PlatUpd] Service launched successfully from: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Offline Scanner`

Usually the log contains a lot of lines with the string `Internal signature match:subtype=Lowfi`, but these don't seem to be real virus detections: They don't show up in Threat History and virustotal.com finds nothing ("No engines detected this file").

According to Moderator/Microsoft Agent Justine Pel in a [thread in the Microsoft Community Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning-windows_10/interpret-windows-defender-mplog-log-files/3036a74c-4365-4a15-acef-cac96e75975d), the log files are intended for submitting Windows Defender errors to Microsoft, therefore I suspect the `Internal match` entries are included for debugging purposes only:

> Those logs are usually use for submission of errors or problems with
>   Windows Defender. Our Windows Defender team are the one who are
>   capable of providing the exact meaning of those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `C:\Windows\Microsoft Antimalware\Support\` open `msssWrapper.log` and near at the end it should say

> Scan completed successfully

.

Comment: It would seem that THIS is indeed the correct log file for offline scans. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My **non-offline** scan text logs have been located at:

*identical copies at both locations on my Win10 20H2:*

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Support\`

`c:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Support\`

*Win7 year 2021 scans logs:*

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Support\`

*Win7 year 2019 scans logs:*

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Support\`

An above post suggested this location for **offline** scan logs:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft Antimalware\Support\`

Answer (score -2):

Right-click on the Start button and choose Event Viewer. Then navigate to Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender > Operational:

Comment: I don't see any results or summary here--just `Windows Defender Antivirus downloaded and configured Windows Defender Offline to run on the next reboot.` logged beforehand. I'm using Windows 10.0.18363.592.